# jQuery serialize nested form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form inside another form element but when I try to serialize the nested form the function just returns an empty object. I ask this because I'm coding a Wordpress plugin and I need a form in the post editor page and everything I put in the page seems to be added inside a parent form, so here is an exmaple of what I want:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xdydtset)

```
<form>
<div>Other content goes here...</div>
<form id="otroform"><input type="text" value="meine valor" name="variable"/></form>
</form>
```

This is the JS code

```
var formData = jQuery('#otroform').serializeArray();
console.log(formData);
```

Returns:

```
[]
```

If I remove the parent form then it will work normally.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HTML forbids nested forms. Don't create them in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

serializeArray() doesn't require a form. So, you can pull this off without the inside form by collecting the input(s) by a distinct class.

For example:

html:

```
<form>
<div>Other content goes here...</div>
<form id="otroform"><input type="text" class="otroform" value="meine valor" name="variable"/></form>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
var formData = jQuery('.otroform').serializeArray();
console.log(formData);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bz5ddf1L/

see .serializeArray() documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code to have the outer form use the ID it works:

```
<form id="otroform">
    <div>Other content goes here...</div>
    <form id=""><input type="text" value="meine valor" name="variable"/></form>
</form>
```

This is because of the issue of nested forms which you cannot have.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xdydtset/1/

Answer (score -1):

You can't have nested forms. You can have different forms, but not nested forms.

Look here for references: [Can you nest html forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms)